# Increasing versatility of parsing - Java

Tags: java, arrays, parsing

I'm developing a program which takes a .txt, retrieves the numbers from it, and puts them into an array for further analysis. Here's what I've got, where 'line' is the string coming in-

```
stringArray = line.split(" ");

                doubleArray = new double[stringArray.length];
                    for(int i=0; i<stringArray.length; i++)
                        {
                           doubleArray[i] = Double.parseDouble(stringArray[i]);
                        }
```

This works if the string is something like "6.5 8 2 4.3 1 67".
However, I'm trying to get it to filter out commas, multiple spaces, and other letters too. I think this just has to do with modifying the .split part, but I'm unsure how.

Any ideas?

Comment: If a comma is contained in the string, is it considered part of the number (e.g. 2,453 = two thousand four hundred fifty three) or is it a delimiter (e.g. 2,452 = two and four hundred fifty three)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example:

```
stringArray = line.split("[^0-9.+Ee-]+");
```

will split on any set of characters that are not 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9, '.', '+', 'E', 'e' or '-' - which are all the characters that can appear in a double.

Answer (score 0):

You may go through line char by char retrieving only digits and points, then use `line.spit()` on the purified string. I think this would be faster than regexp when you analyze a lot of data.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Apache commons lang StringUtil](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html) class.
Check out the split method.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [Scanner](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) to do the work for you.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

Scanner s = new Scanner(myInputString);
s.useDelimiter(",");
List<Double> doubles = new ArrayList<Double>();
while( s.hasNextDouble() ) {
    doubles.add(s.nextDouble())
}
```

You can tweak what is passed in to useDelimiter to suite your needs.